# Не удается создать фотоальбом с использованием Aiogram и MediaGroupBuilder

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, asyncio

Я работаю над функцией в Telegram-боте на Python, используя библиотеку Aiogram, которая должна создавать фотоальбом из полученных фотографий в сообщении и отправлять его пользователям. Однако, несмотря на то что код выполняется без ошибок, альбом не создается, и фотографии не отправляются как ожидалось. Вот часть кода, отвечающая за создание альбома:

```
# Обработка фотографий (создание альбома)
if message.photo:
    media_group = MediaGroupBuilder()
    unique_photos = set()  # Для хранения уникальных file_id
    photos_count = {}  # Словарь для подсчета количества каждой фотографии

    for photo_size_array in message.photo:
        photo_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
        if photo_id not in unique_photos:
            unique_photos.add(photo_id)
            photos_count[photo_id] = 1
            media_group.add_photo(media=photo_id)
        else:
            photos_count[photo_id] += 1

    caption = message.caption if message.caption else None

    if len(unique_photos) == 1:
        photo_id = next(iter(unique_photos))
        if photos_count[photo_id] == 1:
            for user_id in users:
                await bot.send_photo(chat_id=user_id[0], photo=photo_id, caption=caption)
        else:
            for user_id in users:
                await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=user_id[0], media=media_group.build())
    elif len(unique_photos) > 1:
        for user_id in users:
            await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=user_id[0], media=media_group.build())
```

Могли бы вы подсказать, что я делаю не так или что мне нужно изменить, чтобы альбом формировался и отправлялся корректно?